# MySQL 5.6.36 crashed suddenly - Assertion failure. How to track it?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Yesterday my database crashed and then restarted; after the automatic crash recovery started normally and it's working fine; is there a way to know what caused it? I tried searching in the binlogs for some "strange" query or something with the log, but can't find what happened. Here's what the error log shows:

```
2017-08-30 16:33:19 7f87ddacb700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140221516396288 in file row0sel.cc line 2840 
InnoDB: Failing assertion: prebuilt->trx->isolation_level == TRX_ISO_READ_UNCOMMITTED InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap. 
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com. 
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even 
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be 
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to 
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery. 
21:33:19 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ; 
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured. 
This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware. We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=268435456
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=110 
max_threads=250 
thread_count=56 
connection_count=54 It is possible that mysqld could use up to key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1289343 K  bytes of memory Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x37913940 
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went terribly wrong... 
stack_bottom = 7f87ddacaec0 thread_stack 0x40000 
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0x8e770b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x491)[0x674bb1] 
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf370)[0x7f906980d370] 
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f90684081d7] 
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f90684098c8] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x585801] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x585e6f] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9c69ff] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x91e361] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler17ha_index_read_mapEPhPKhm16ha_rkey_function+0xe4)[0x5b7804] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler16read_range_firstEPK12st_key_rangeS2_bb+0x66)[0x5bbba6] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler21multi_range_read_nextEPPc+0x86)[0x5b3736]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN18QUICK_RANGE_SELECT8get_nextEv+0x5a)[0x7f4aea]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x81887d] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10sub_selectP4JOINP13st_join_tableb+0xdd)[0x6d013d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x408)[0x6cf4a8] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListI4ItemEPS4_P10SQL_I_ListI8st_orderESB_S7_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0x275)[0x7180b5] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP13select_resultm+0x195)[0x718945] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x57a508] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x269e)[0x6f35ee]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x368)[0x6f7838] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0xf82)[0x6f8f62]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x152)[0x6c5fe2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x40)[0x6c60a0] 
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dc5)[0x7f9069805dc5] 
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f90684ca76d]

Trying to get some variables. 
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort. 
Query (7f858e4f9420): is an invalid pointer 
Connection ID (thread ID): 442657 
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

The SO is CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core). Also searched for SO errors but the only thing found was something after it crashed (something from "sd.collector... Can't connect to MySQL server").

Is there something I'm missing? Tried searching some errors like that, but there are many and very different. I would like to know if I can know what caused it and if it can happen again.

Answer (score 1):

We've seen this in my shop, and traced it to this bug, fixed here in mysqld 5.7-22.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-22.html

InnoDB: An assertion was raised when a thread attempted to read a record containing BLOB data while another thread was writing the same data to external pages. (Bug #26300119)

Answer (score 0):

The error log was trying to handle_one_connection near the end.
max_threads=250 is probably more than necessary since max_used_connections=110 (high water mark) and current connection_count was 54 when the error log was recorded.
key_buffer_size is very large.
read_buffer_size of 1M will likely reduce the time to process queries and reduce the per thread memory footprint required.
It would be helpful to know how much RAM ( memory ) you have.
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS  would all be helpful.

Comment: Add to that- How much RAM.